# Telerik controls not getting loaded in VSTO application deployed using Click Once

Tags: telerik, vsto

I am using Telerik Tree View control in Excel VSTO Application.  The Tree View control is added in the Document action pane. I am deploying VSTO application using Click Once. In the deployment deployment folder I see the  dll's Telerik.WinControls.dll.deploy, TelerikCommon.dll.deploy,Telerik.WinControls.UI.dll.deploy .

But on openning the workbook the Tree View control is not gettting loaded and it is not throwing any error either. I am using the Telerik Trial version.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to reproduce the issue with a regular Windows Forms application?

I do believe the issue is cause by the trial edition of Telerik controls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right the problem was the trial version. With licenced version it worked fine.